# Change column name by looking up

Tags: r, dataframe

I know that I can change a data.frame column name by:

```
colnames(df)[3] <- "newname"
```

But there might be cases where the column I want to change is not in the 3rd position. Is there a way to look up the column by name and change it? Like this...

```
colnames(df)[,"oldname"] <- "newname"
```

BTW, I have tried this code and I keep getting `incorrect number of subscripts on matrix`.

Thanks.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

```
colnames(df)[colnames(df)=="oldname"] <- "newname"
```

or just `names`

```
names(df)[names(df)=="oldname"] <- "newname"
```

There are various functions for renaming columns in packages as well.

Answer (score 5):

```
colnames(df)[colnames(df)=="oldname"] <- "newname"
```

**or**

```
names(df)[names(df)=="oldname"] <- "newname"
```

(since `names` and `colnames` are equivalent for a data frame)

**or** you might be looking for

```
library(reshape)
df <- rename(df,c(oldname="newname"))
```

Answer (score 5):

I was using package `data.table` today and when I tried to change a column name using my usual method a message appeared recommending this approach:

```
library(data.table)

df <- read.table(text= "
          region    state  county
             1        1       1  
             1        2       2  
             1        2       3 
             2        1       4
             2        1       4
", header=TRUE, na.strings=NA)

df

setnames(df, "county", "district")

df
```

Answer (score 3):

A somewhat more general approach that will replace all of the "old"s at the beginning of any current name with "new" in the same character location:

```
names(df) <- sub("^old", "new", names(df) )
```